# PHP Login with salt+encryption

Tags: php, encryption, hash, salt

The problem is that I am simply trying to login with this script and the only times I can make it work is if I take out the lines retrieving the salt from the database based off of the username provided and put in the hashed password manually. The weird part about this whole problem is this is the exact way I do it on another site I made and it works flawlessly. What happens is that it blanks the page and doesnt even show an error. If anyone has a solution I would be very happy to hear them or suggestions about a better way to do this.

```
<?php
include 'includes/calendar-functions.php';
//user login
if(isset($_POST['membership_id']) && isset($_POST['user_password']) && $_POST['membership_id'] != "" && $_POST['user_password'] != "" ) {
    //Setting up VARS
    $newUsername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['membership_id']);
    $newPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_password']);
    $saltQuery = 'SELECT `salt` FROM `vintage_user` WHERE membership_id = '.$newUsername;
    $resultSalt = mysql_query($saltQuery, $connect) or die( mysql_error() );

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSalt)) {
        $salt = $row["salt"];
    }

    $saltedPW =  $newPassword . $salt;
    $hashedPW = hash('sha256', $saltedPW);

    // QUERYING DB FOR USERNAME AND PASSWORD
    $query = 'SELECT *
        FROM vintage_user
        WHERE membership_id = "'.$newUsername.'"
        AND user_password = "'.$hashedPW.'"
        AND approved = "1"
        LIMIT 1';
    $result = mysql_query( $query, $mysql ) or die( mysql_error() );

    if( mysql_num_rows( $result ) == 1 ) {
        list( $_SESSION['user_first'],
            $_SESSION['user_last'],
            $_SESSION['user_id'],
            $_SESSION['user_email'],
            $_SESSION['membership_id'] ) = mysql_fetch_row( $result );
        header( 'location:'.'calendar.php?m='.$month.'d=1&y='.$year );
        die();
    }
    else {
        echo '<p class="incorrect">Incorrect login and/or password</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Find your real error file on the server (`/var/log/httpd/error.log` for CentOS machines), because I guarantee that an error is occurring - you're just not seeing it.

Comment: I checked out the log file and it turns out my second parameter in a sql query was not a resource...weird so I checked out and it was misspelled, changed it and it worked. Thank you, next time I will dig a little deeper into the issue and defiantly check out the log.

Comment: You should also look into [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). This will prevent any 'not a resource' errors because it lets you deal with objects (and adds plenty of great features) instead of resources.

Comment: Use PDO and it can prevent a lot of unwanted actions. Also, check to make sure $newUsername is actually getting a value, it seems like there may be an error with the query.

Comment: Also, use `bcrypt` or `PBKDF2` for you password hashing, `sha256` is not secure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If magic_quotes_gpc is enabled, first apply stripslashes() to the data. Using this function on data which has already been escaped will escape the data twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try the blowfish encryption method, it worked for me.

functions.php

```
<?php
 include_once("Blowfish.php");
   function Eencrypt($cipher, $plaintext){
      $ciphertext = "";
      $paddedtext = maxi_pad($plaintext);
      $strlen = strlen($paddedtext);
      for($x=0; $x< $strlen; $x+=8){
         $piece = substr($paddedtext,$x,8);
         $cipher_piece = $cipher->encrypt($piece);
         $encoded = base64_encode($cipher_piece); 
         $ciphertext = $ciphertext.$encoded;       
      }
   return $ciphertext;  
   }

   function Edecrypt($cipher,$ciphertext){
      $plaintext = "";
      $chunks = explode("=",$ciphertext);
      $ending_value = count($chunks) ;
      for($counter=0 ; $counter < ($ending_value-1) ; $counter++)
      {
            $chunk = $chunks[$counter]."=";
            $decoded = base64_decode($chunk);
            $piece = $cipher->decrypt($decoded);
            $plaintext = $plaintext.$piece;
      }
      return $plaintext;
   }

   function maxi_pad($plaintext){
      $str_len = count($plaintext);
      //plain text must be div by 8
      $pad_len = $str_len % 8;
      for($x=0; $x<$pad_len; $x++){
         $plaintext = $plaintext." ";
      }

      $str_len = count($plaintext);
      if($str_len % 8){
         print "padding function is not working\n";
      }else{
         return $plaintext;
      }
      return (-1);
   }
?>
```

blowfish.php

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4: */

/**
 * Crypt_Blowfish allows for encryption and decryption on the fly using
 * the Blowfish algorithm. Crypt_Blowfish does not require the mcrypt
 * PHP extension, it uses only PHP.
 * Crypt_Blowfish support encryption/decryption with or without a secret key.
 *
 *
 * PHP versions 4 and 5
 *
 * LICENSE: This source file is subject to version 3.0 of the PHP license
 * that is available through the world-wide-web at the following URI:
 * http://www.php.net/license/3_0.txt.  If you did not receive a copy of
 * the PHP License and are unable to obtain it through the web, please
 * send a note to license@php.net so we can mail you a copy immediately.
 *
 * @category   Encryption
 * @package    Crypt_Blowfish
 * @author     Matthew Fonda <mfonda@php.net>
 * @copyright  2005 Matthew Fonda
 * @license    http://www.php.net/license/3_0.txt  PHP License 3.0
 * @version    CVS: $Id: Blowfish.php,v 1.81 2005/05/30 18:40:36 mfonda Exp $
 * @link       http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_Blowfish
 */


require_once 'PEAR.php';


/**
 *
 * Example usage:
 * $bf = new Crypt_Blowfish('some secret key!');
 * $encrypted = $bf->encrypt('this is some example plain text');
 * $plaintext = $bf->decrypt($encrypted);
 * echo "plain text: $plaintext";
 *
 *
 * @category   Encryption
 * @package    Crypt_Blowfish
 * @author     Matthew Fonda <mfonda@php.net>
 * @copyright  2005 Matthew Fonda
 * @license    http://www.php.net/license/3_0.txt  PHP License 3.0
 * @link       http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_Blowfish
 * @version    @package_version@
 * @access     public
 */
class Crypt_Blowfish
{
    /**
     * P-Array contains 18 32-bit subkeys
     *
     * @var array
     * @access private
     */
    var $_P = array();


    /**
     * Array of four S-Blocks each containing 256 32-bit entries
     *
     * @var array
     * @access private
     */
    var $_S = array();

    /**
     * Mcrypt td resource
     *
     * @var resource
     * @access private
     */
    var $_td = null;

    /**
     * Initialization vector
     *
     * @var string
     * @access private
     */
    var $_iv = null;


    /**
     * Crypt_Blowfish Constructor
     * Initializes the Crypt_Blowfish object, and gives a sets
     * the secret key
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @access public
     */
    function Crypt_Blowfish($key)
    {
        if (extension_loaded('mcrypt')) {
            $this->_td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, '', 'ecb', '');
            $this->_iv = mcrypt_create_iv(8, MCRYPT_RAND);
        }
        $this->setKey($key);
    }

    /**
     * Deprecated isReady method
     *
     * @return bool
     * @access public
     * @deprecated
     */
    function isReady()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Deprecated init method - init is now a private
     * method and has been replaced with _init
     *
     * @return bool
     * @access public
     * @deprecated
     * @see Crypt_Blowfish::_init()
     */
    function init()
    {
        $this->_init();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the Crypt_Blowfish object
     *
     * @access private
     */
    function _init()
    {
        $defaults = new Crypt_Blowfish_DefaultKey();
        $this->_P = $defaults->P;
        $this->_S = $defaults->S;
    }

    /**
     * Enciphers a single 64 bit block
     *
     * @param int &$Xl
     * @param int &$Xr
     * @access private
     */
    function _encipher(&$Xl, &$Xr)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++) {
            $temp = $Xl ^ $this->_P[$i];
            $Xl = ((($this->_S[0][($temp>>24) & 255] +
                            $this->_S[1][($temp>>16) & 255]) ^
                            $this->_S[2][($temp>>8) & 255]) +
                            $this->_S[3][$temp & 255]) ^ $Xr;
            $Xr = $temp;
        }
        $Xr = $Xl ^ $this->_P[16];
        $Xl = $temp ^ $this->_P[17];
    }


    /**
     * Deciphers a single 64 bit block
     *
     * @param int &$Xl
     * @param int &$Xr
     * @access private
     */
    function _decipher(&$Xl, &$Xr)
    {
        for ($i = 17; $i > 1; $i--) {
            $temp = $Xl ^ $this->_P[$i];
            $Xl = ((($this->_S[0][($temp>>24) & 255] +
                            $this->_S[1][($temp>>16) & 255]) ^
                            $this->_S[2][($temp>>8) & 255]) +
                            $this->_S[3][$temp & 255]) ^ $Xr;
            $Xr = $temp;
        }
        $Xr = $Xl ^ $this->_P[1];
        $Xl = $temp ^ $this->_P[0];
    }


    /**
     * Encrypts a string
     *
     * @param string $plainText
     * @return string Returns cipher text on success, PEAR_Error on failure
     * @access public
     */
    function encrypt($plainText)
    {
        if (!is_string($plainText)) {
            PEAR::raiseError('Plain text must be a string', 0, PEAR_ERROR_DIE);
        }

        if (extension_loaded('mcrypt')) {
            return mcrypt_generic($this->_td, $plainText);
        }

        $cipherText = '';
        $len = strlen($plainText);
        $plainText .= str_repeat(chr(0),(8 - ($len%8))%8);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += 8) {
            list(,$Xl,$Xr) = unpack("N2",substr($plainText,$i,8));
            $this->_encipher($Xl, $Xr);
            $cipherText .= pack("N2", $Xl, $Xr);
        }
        return $cipherText;
    }


    /**
     * Decrypts an encrypted string
     *
     * @param string $cipherText
     * @return string Returns plain text on success, PEAR_Error on failure
     * @access public
     */
    function decrypt($cipherText)
    {

        if (!is_string($cipherText)) {
            PEAR::raiseError('Chiper text must be a string', 1, PEAR_ERROR_DIE);
        }

        if (extension_loaded('mcrypt')) {
            return mdecrypt_generic($this->_td, $cipherText);
        }

        $plainText = '';
        $len = strlen($cipherText);
        $cipherText .= str_repeat(chr(0),(8 - ($len%8))%8);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += 8) {
            list(,$Xl,$Xr) = unpack("N2",substr($cipherText,$i,8));
            $this->_decipher($Xl, $Xr);
            $plainText .= pack("N2", $Xl, $Xr);
        }
        return $plainText;
    }


    /**
     * Sets the secret key
     * The key must be non-zero, and less than or equal to
     * 56 characters in length.
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @return bool  Returns true on success, PEAR_Error on failure
     * @access public
     */
    function setKey($key)
    {
        if (!is_string($key)) {
            PEAR::raiseError('Key must be a string', 2, PEAR_ERROR_DIE);
        }

        $len = strlen($key);

        if ($len > 56 || $len == 0) {
            PEAR::raiseError('Key must be less than 56 characters and non-zero. Supplied key length: ' . $len, 3, PEAR_ERROR_DIE);
        }

        if (extension_loaded('mcrypt')) {
            mcrypt_generic_init($this->_td, $key, $this->_iv);
            return true;
        }

        require_once 'Blowfish/DefaultKey.php';
        $this->_init();

        $k = 0;
        $data = 0;
        $datal = 0;
        $datar = 0;

        for ($i = 0; $i < 18; $i++) {
            $data = 0;
            for ($j = 4; $j > 0; $j--) {
                    $data = $data << 8 | ord($key{$k});
                    $k = ($k+1) % $len;
            }
            $this->_P[$i] ^= $data;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i <= 16; $i += 2) {
            $this->_encipher($datal, $datar);
            $this->_P[$i] = $datal;
            $this->_P[$i+1] = $datar;
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i += 2) {
            $this->_encipher($datal, $datar);
            $this->_S[0][$i] = $datal;
            $this->_S[0][$i+1] = $datar;
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i += 2) {
            $this->_encipher($datal, $datar);
            $this->_S[1][$i] = $datal;
            $this->_S[1][$i+1] = $datar;
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i += 2) {
            $this->_encipher($datal, $datar);
            $this->_S[2][$i] = $datal;
            $this->_S[2][$i+1] = $datar;
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i += 2) {
            $this->_encipher($datal, $datar);
            $this->_S[3][$i] = $datal;
            $this->_S[3][$i+1] = $datar;
        }

        return true;
    }

}

?>
```

example.php

```
<?php

   include_once('functions.php');
   include_once('blowfish.php');


   //NOTE: This is the key or password for encrypting your files.
   // THIS MUST BE 8 CHARACTERS
   $key = "12345678";

   //This is the text to be encrypted
   $plaintext = "stringtoencrypt";

   //This is a blowfish cipher object
   $cipher = new Crypt_Blowfish($key); 

   //This is the encrypted text
   $ciphertext = Eencrypt($cipher,$plaintext);
   $ciphertext = $plaintext;

   print $ciphertext."</br>"; 

   //If the var to decrypt is sent by $_GET
   $key = "";
   $url = explode(" ",$_GET['key']);      
   for ($i=0; $i < count($url)-1; $i++) { 
      @$key .= $url[$i]."+";
   }
   $key = $key.array_pop($url);

   //This is the Decrypted text.
   $desencriptado = Edecrypt($cipher, $key);  

   print "desencriptado es: ".$desencriptado;    
?>
```